# How can I description localstorage in route of Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, router

I need to check my token in the router every page. and I need to use beforeEach. I do in the vue. but I dont use in nuxt.js. my question how can I use my localstorage in router of nuxt.js. my code example like this in `route.js` file.

```
export default ({ app, store, redirect }) => {

app.router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    store.state.tokenim = localStorage.getItem("token");

    if (store.state.tokenim == '') 
    next();
})}
```

I write like this. and I take a mistake in the console like this.

```
[vue-router] uncaught error during route navigation:                                                                                                                               
 ERROR  localStorage is not defined
```

help please :)

Answer (score 1):

When you add route.js to as a plugin, you should set ssr:false

```js
plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/hello.js', ssr: false }
]
```